# How do I uninstall an addon in opera (for Mac)?

Tags: browser, opera

Decided to give the [Opera browser](http://www.opera.com) a try today, since I do believe that competition between different browsers is a Good Thing. Anyway, I managed to mess up a bit and installed the wrong "ad-blocking" addon (Addblockplus instead of Add-block...).

So, how on earth do I get rid of that addon? I can find no way to get rid of it. Google does not help me; I cannot find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer while writing the question: Window -> Extensions. From there you can easily get rid of it. Stupid user? Mayhaps. :)